# Huge rake task not completing on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

So i've got a rake task on my rails application which populated my db from a CSV

However this is populating around 40k rows,

How do i go about making this run all the way without stopping?

Heres the rake task (edited)

```
viacsv.each do |vrow|
  viadate = vrow[10].split(' ')[0]
  viatime = vrow[10].split(' ')[1]
  vianame = vrow[8]
  viaurl = vrow[9]
  csv.each do |row|
    Event.find_or_create_by(time: row[9], date: row[10], eventurl1: row[8], eventname: row[7])
    link = viacsv.find_by(['eventname LIKE ?', "%#{vianame}%"])
    byebug
  end
end
```

Thanks

Sam

Comment: Hey  Is this your production server? Does `byebug` intercept your rake task?

Comment: its on my production server, It does put some of the csv file inside, It seems to be stopping

Comment: @HieuPham  Seems like its timing out at 3600 seconds, apparently client connection is idle

Comment: Any log? Maybe the memory was running out!